# Error in SQL query (SQL update)

Tags: mysql, sql

The query is :

```
Update t1
set t1.paper_attempt = 1
from table1 as t1
JOIN table2 as t2
ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id
JOIN table3 as t3
ON t3.id = t2.company_id
where t3.candidate_id = 'CAND024';
```

I am using HeidiSQL, on running the query, it is showing a Syntax error. Please help!

Comment: Can you also provide the schema and error details?

Comment: Sorry! its comapny database. Can't reveal that. But, since its a syntax error, i think the error is in syntax of my query.

Comment: Update does not contain `FROM` . Is not it? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: So, if i want to use short name for my table (in this case t1 for table1), how would i do that ? Also, can't i also use t2 for table2 and t3 for table3  ?

Comment: If you don't want to share "proprietary" schemas that's fine, but you should still take the effort to make a minimal, complete example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax doesn't work in mySQL.

The common multi-table update query is:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_list
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

i.e. your query should be rewritten as:

```
Update table1 as t1, 
       table2 as t2, 
       table3 as t3
set  t1.paper_attempt = 1
where  t2.user_id = t1.user_id
        and t3.id = t2.company_id
        and t3.candidate_id = 'CAND024';
```

Also you can use subquery:

```
Update table1 as t1
set  t1.paper_attempt = 1
where  t1.user_id in (
       select t2.user_id
       from table2 as t2
       join table3 as t3 on (t3.id = t2.company_id)
       where t3.candidate_id = 'CAND024'
);
```